# Constructing homomorphism from a special type of function

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

Let $f:G \to G$ be a function such that $f(a)f(b)f(c)=f(x)f(y)f(z) , \forall a,b,c,x,y,z \in G$ such that $abc=xyz=e$ ; then is it true that $\exists g\in G$ so that $h:G\to G$ defined as $h(x):=gf(x)$ is a homomorphism ?

Comment: Interesting question. Where does it come from?

Comment: If it exists, $g$ is unique : $g=f(e)^{-1}$.

Comment: Please give some motivation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is YES. Taking $a=b=c=e$, the intial hypothesis can be rewritten
as

$$
f(x)f(y)f(y^{-1}x^{-1})=f(e)^3 \ (x,y\in G) \tag{1}
$$
It follows from (1) that $f(e)f(x)f(x^{-1})=f(e)^3=f(x)f(e)f(x^{-1})$, so that
$$
f(e)f(x)=f(x)f(e) \ (x\in G)\tag{2}
$$
(Thanks to [Zoe H](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/168114/zoe-h) for pointing this out). Let us now put $h(x)=f(e)^{-1}f(x)$ ; then $h(x)=f(x)f(e)^{-1}$ by (2), and
$f(x)=f(e)h(x)=h(x)f(e)$. Then (1) yields $f(e)h(x)f(e)h(y)f(e)h(y^{-1}x^{-1})=f(e)^3$, or

$$
h(x)h(y)h(y^{-1}x^{-1})=e \ (x,y\in G) \tag{3}
$$
Taking $y=e$ in (3), we have $h(x^{-1})=h(x)^{-1}$ for any $x$. It follows that
$h(y^{-1}x^{-1})=h(xy)^{-1}$ ; (3) is therefore equivalent to $h(xy)=h(x)h(y)$, and
$h$ is a homomorphism as required.

Comment: In order to extend your proof to non-commutative groups you need only show that $f(e)$ commutes with $f(x)$ for all $x \in G$ but this is true since $f(e)f(x)f(x^{-1}) = f(x)f(e)f(x^{-1})$.

Comment: @ZoeH Included in my proof now, thanks.